# How to access the element of decodedParameters

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have used `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters` and returned values have been pushed into my array (`finalGettersParams.push(...)`)  something like this.

```
   [ Result { __length__: 0 },
  Result {
    '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    __length__: 1 },
  Result {
    '0': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    __length__: 2 } 
    ]
```

Now i want to access individual elements of `"Result"`from my array. I can access `finalGettersParams[2].__length__` and its print 2. However, i am not sure how to access the '0' and  '1' .... like this `finalGettersParams[2].'0'` These 0, 1 are dynamic.. means they can be increased 0, 1, 2, 3 or decreased (depending on my arguments list, you can see in above array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general Javascript question (not specifically related to Ethereum).

**Instead of this:**

```
inalGettersParams[2].'0'
```

**Use this:**

```
inalGettersParams[2]['0']
```

Comment: sorry, i was also thinking so, but could not find the exact term for this scenario.. thanks for your time......

Comment: @AmirAli: You're welcome, no need to apologize for anything here (I just wanted to emphasize that the problem was not Ethereum-related).

Comment: Thanks again...... one more question, I am not sure should I make another question or in this comment will be OK ? Because it's a extension of this question ...
is it possible to give all parameters ('0', '1', ...)  of above mentioned finalGettersParams array to my myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](...finalGettersParams[j]).call({from: account1})... f

Comment: @AmirAli: What's your function's prototype?

Comment: i think, now it does't matter... because now i have function name/methodID and their parameters (in above forms) ... can i use this information to call getters without knowing its prototype.. ?

Comment: @AmirAli: I don't quite understand what you want to pass to the getter. Maybe give an example in order to shed some light on this.

Comment: OK, i should make another question, will it be better for community...